# pugjs not loading css

Tags: css, node.js, pug

I am not able to get my dashboard.pug file to load dashboard.css but it loads dashboard.js. Both are in the same folder as dashboard.pug

I have already used app use express static correctly for the public folder.

```js
const publicpath=path.join(__dirname,'../public');

app.use(express.static(publicpath));
```

**dashboard.pug-**

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title Dashboard
        script(src='/views/dashboard/dashboard.js')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/views/dashboard/dashboard.css')
    body
        div .navbar
            div .navleft
                p Your notes
            div .navright
                div .dropdown
                    p Account &#9660;
                div .dropdowncontent
                    p Settings
                    p Logout
```

dashboard.js loads successfully

dashboard.css not loading

```
folder structure
-public
 -views
  -dashboard
   -dashboard.css
   -dashboard.js
   -dashboard.pug
-server
 -server.js
```

No errors

Comment: I use 'public' not '../public'. I will try and test your code to see if this is relevant or not.

Comment: @user3425506 I use '../public' because it is outside the server folder

Comment: I just saw that! Why do you not put the pug files in /views (ie. a directory at the root of the app)? That is how express application generator sets it up.

Comment: @user3425506 put files outside dashboard you mean? I tried just now and still the same problem

Comment: Make a views directory in the root of the app and put pug files in it. Then just use 'public'. I just got that working with dashboard.js and dashboard.css in /public/views/dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the gaps between class name and div. Somehow it showed no error and rendered HTML divs with a class but those classes did not call CSS. I removed the gaps like this

`div .classname  -> div.classname`

and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I set up a very similar app to yours using express application generator. The directory structure (not showing *node_modules*) looks like this:

```
.
├── app.js
├── bin
│   └── www
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── public
│   ├── images
│   ├── javascripts
│   ├── stylesheets
│   │   └── style.css
│   └── views
│       └── dashboard
│           ├── dashboard.css
│           └── dashboard.js
├── routes
│   ├── index.js
│   └── users.js
└── views
    ├── error.pug
    ├── index.pug
    └── layout.pug
```

Note that the `index.pug` file is in `/views` (*index.pug* is equivalent to your *dashboard.pug*).

**index.pug:**

```
    html
      head
        title Dashboard
        script(src='/views/dashboard/dashboard.js')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/views/dashboard/dashboard.css')
      body
      p Hi!
```

In `app.js` the express application generator puts in the line:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

The simple css and js files I put in `/public/views/dashboard` worked when I viewed the `index.pug` page rendered in the browser.

Hope this helps.

Comment: One more thing. I am wondering if it is a very good idea to have a views directory in /public. As you can see express application generator makes a javascript and a stylesheets directory inside public to put these files in.